# Order of execution of nested functions in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

When I use nested function in a piping step, the order of execution seems unintuitive.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,NA,2), b = c(NA, NA, 1))
df %>% is.na %>% colSums # Produce correct count of missing values
df %>% colSums(is.na(.)) # Produce NA
```

Can anyone explain why the nested function in the third line does not produce the correct result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because the `.` always gets passed as the first argument to the following function. So in your second attempt at `colSums`, you assume that you're passing `is.na(.)` as the first argument to `colSums`, but you're actually passing it as the second, which is the `na.rm` parameter. So what your code actually looks like is `df %>% colSums(x = ., na.rm = is.na(.))`. You can prevent the `.` being passed as the first parameter by using `{}` around the function. `df %>% {colSums(is.na(.))}`